# Printing sequence of strings either using a newlines or without

Tags: bash, printing

I am having a go at printing a sequence of strings, either using a newline between entries.  Or printing them next to each other.

Would like to simplify this if I can.

When `nwline=1`, new lines are used between the printing of arguments.  When `nwline=0`, arguments are printed on same line.

`nl` determines the number of arguments that get coloured using `ctp`.

```
pfm ()
{
    nwline=0
    nl=3
    ctp=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 39)

    if (( nl >= 1 )); then
      case $nwline in
       1) printf '%s\n' "${ctp}${@:1:nl}${rst}" ;;
       *) printf '%s' "${ctp}${@:1:nl}${rst}" ;;
      esac
      if (( nl + 1 <= $# )); then
        case $nwline in
         1) printf '%s\n' "${@:nl+1}" ;;
         *) printf '%s' "${@:nl+1}" ;;
        esac
      fi
    else
      case $nwline in
       1) printf '%s\n' "$@" ;;
       *) printf '%s' "$@" ;;
      esac
    fi
}
```

Using suggestions I did the following

```
aggr=("$@")
nk=$((nl-1))

rst=$(tput sgr0) ; ctp=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 39)

(( nwline == 1 )) && fs=$'\n' || fs=' '
( IFS=$fs ; echo "${ctp}${aggr[*]:0:nk}${rst}" )
(( nl + 1 <= $# )) && ( IFS=$fs ; echo "${aggr[*]:nl}" )
```

But when I use `pfm "Mary" "had" "a" "little" "lamb"`, I get

```
Mary
had
little
lamb
```

As observed, I am missing the `"a"`.

Comment: Can you privide a short but full code including the assignments to the variables such as `nwline`, `ctp`, `rst`, `nl` and the arguments `$@`? We cannot test the snippet with a lot of undefined variables.

Comment: There are almost certainly better ways.

Comment: I am particularly interested in simplifying the printing using newlines or without, where I am using the `case` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
pfm ()
{
    local nwline=1
    local nl=3
    local ctp=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 39)
    local rst=$(tput sgr0)
    local -a ary=("$@")                         # make a copy of arguments
    local fs                                    # field separator: "\n" or ""

    if (( nl > $# )); then nl=$#; fi            # limit the value of nl
    for (( i = 0; i < nl; i++ )); do            # highlight the elements indexed lower than nl
        ary[i]="${ctp}${ary[i]}${rst}"
    done

    (( nwline == 1 )) && fs=$'\n' || fs=''      # assign fs to the field separator

    (IFS=$fs; echo "${ary[*]}")                 # execute in subshell not to modify IFS
}
```

As for the printing of the elements using newline or without, I have
used the array variable expansion `"${name[*]}"` which expands
to a concatenation of array elements separated by the first character of `IFS`.

Comment: Can one set an array in the following way,  `aggr=( "${ctp}${@:1:nl}${rst}" )`.

Comment: I have tried it, but still getting things printed on the same line.

Comment: As for your 1st question, it will work if you can combine `aggr` with the rest of the array to print them altogether. Regarding the 2nd question, I have no idea why it doesn't work in your environment. What is your bash version?

Comment: It works with changing `IFS` in a subshell.  Thanks.  At first things failed but now got it to work.